# How to kill a specific .NET application process when multiple dotnet processes are running?

Tags: c#, .net, process, .net-6.0

I have a (primary) .NET application which has to use another (secondary) .NET application, so I run the secondary application by using `Process.Start()` in the primary application.

```cs
public void LaunchApp(string appFolder, string appName)
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new()
    {
        WorkingDirectory = appFolder,
        CreateNoWindow   = false,
        UseShellExecute  = true,
        FileName         = "dotnet",
        WindowStyle      = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
        Arguments        = $"{appName}.dll arg_1 arg_2",
    };

    try
    {
        using Process? process = Process.Start(startInfo);
        process?.WaitForExit();
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

However, I cannot have multiple instances of the secondary application.

So Before starting the secondary application, I use `Process.GetProcesses()` to find the running instance and kill it using `process.Kill()` or `process.CloseMainWindow()`.

The problem is, `Process.GetProcesses()` returns "dotnet" instead of, lets say "secondary.dll". Which I can understand because the `FileName` of `startInfo` was "dotnet", and not "secondary.dll". So I cannot know for sure which application I'm going to kill. And if I kill all of "dotnet" instances then my primary application terminates itself as well.

My question is, what is the proper way to do this?

I know I can run `ps -x` using `Process.Start()` to find all the processes running and parse whatever is returned by that, and it would technically give me the results I want. But there has to be a way to deal with this without resorting to terminal commands.

Any help or insight would be highly appreciated. :)

Comment: Are you the author of both programs? If so, there are better ways of signalling between processes than just having one process kill the other.

Comment: You can use `process.ProcessName` to retrieve the name of the secondary process you started, if I understand the question correctly.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever unfortunately I am not the author of the secondary program. I have to launch it somehow and also make sure that only one instance is running.

Comment: @ndogac Yes that is exactly what I do. But `process.ProcessName` comes out to be `dotnet`, and not `secondary.dll`

Comment: @UsmanMehmood One workaround you can consider is that you can pass command line arguments to your second process. When checking if it's the second process, you can check whether `process.StartInfo.Arguments` contains your command line argument.

Comment: @ndogac sadly that doesn't work. Getting `process.StartInfo` throws an exception with the message "Process was not started by this object, so requested information cannot be determined."